# What can cause a click event to not fire properly?

Tags: asp.net, events

I have a page with a ckeditor in it, and a "save button".
On load, i put some text on the editor for the user to edit and then save.
I am experiencing some troubles with the save button.

I have the following code on my code behind.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Some Code

Protected Sub btgravar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btgravar.Click
    Some Code
```

In normal cases, and if i put a breakpoint on the first line of the two events, the page load is fired and then the click event.
In some cases (and i couldn't figure out when) the click event is not fired. The page load fires, and then the page refreshes without any signal of the save button.

I thought that if some exception was thrown on the page load event, this could prevent the second event from firing. However, i followed all the code in debug mode and there's no exception thrown and when it comes to and end, the page simply refreshes.

Any idea on why this is happening?

**EDIT**: The editor and the buttons (save and return) are inside a table, here it is some of the aspx code (the table closing element is not there because there's more cede below this one)

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; height: 18px;" id="TABLE1" language="javascript" onclick="return TABLE1_onclick()">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 24px; height: 25px; text-align: right">
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/Imagens/retorna.gif"
                                            Width="20px" /></td>
                                                <td style="width: 7px; height: 25px;">
                                                    <span style="font-size: 8pt; color: black">&nbsp;Cancelar</span></td>
                                                <td style="width: 28px; height: 25px; text-align: right">
                                                    <asp:ImageButton  ID="btgravar" runat="server" Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/Imagens/gravar.gif"
                                            Width="20px" ToolTip="Gravar Relatório" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="width: 46px; height: 25px;">
                                                    <span style="font-size: 8pt; color: #006666">&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblgravar" runat="server"
                                                        Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black">Gravar</asp:Label></span></td>
```

-

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

-

```
function TABLE1_onclick() {

}
```

The TABLE1_onclick() has actually no meaning and probably can be taken out from the table definition(?)

**EDIT2**: I tried removing the onclick from the table: no change. I have also already tried to take the image button off the table and directly into the page and the behaviour persists.

(If you want me to provide more details/code of my page, just ask)

Comment: Can you post relevant aspx code please?

Comment: The page has 350 lines so will you tell me which parts do you think relevant please? I just added some aspx from the buttons part.

Comment: Button , Form  (if any), Javascript (like Tabel1_onclick()), Validator ,

Answer (score 1):

I think I see something:

btgravar is missing the OnClick event handler.  You should add **OnClick="btgravar_Click"** to the image button.

If you are adding it somewhere in your page load with

```
btgravar.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(btgravar_Click);
```

and make sure you are doing it on every page load even on postback.

Edit:  the onclick would only cancel the action if it was return false, and you did return in the onClick as well.  This is what I originally thought, but I did some testing with what you posted and it seems like it is ok.

Comment: I thought the same once i saw that the function was actually empty. Removing it doesn't make any difference, though.

Comment: I copied your code and noticed something so I updated my answer. Looks like you are using VB so the attach handler code for page load may be different, but the declarative method should be the same.

Comment: I think the attach between the image button and the function are fine because there are times in which it works properly.

Comment: I can't really figure out how this works sometimes, and some others it doesn't.